# Change Variable Value in JVM with GDB

Tags: java, jvm, gdb, inject

Currently I have a simple Java program:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean test = true;
    while (test) {
      System.out.println("Hello World");
      try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    System.out.println("Bye-bye");
  }
}
```

It prints "Hello World" every second. I would like to use gdb to attach to the process and make a memory patch to stop it with "Bye-bye" printed.

I know GDB can get created VMs (JNI_GetCreatedVMs) from its console, the env object is also available via the API of GetEnv. **How can I** find the `test` variable address in JVM and set it to false (this is optional) to **make the program exit normally?** Not sure if API like AttachCurrentThread, class like HotSpotVirtualMachine, tools like jmap or jstack can help?

And there is no debug option, assume the simple program running in production with `java -cp . Test`.

Thanks in advance for any guidance. :)

---

#### additional info (track state)

- `jmap -dump:file=hex <pid> && jhat hex` and browse at http://localhost:7000; cannot find any reference to `test` (it is not an object and just an instance of `class Z`)
- `jstack <pid>` can get the tid of main thread (0x7fa412002000) and `jhat hex` has the object of the java.lang.Thread of main (0x76ab05c40)
- `java.lang.Thread` has a native method `start0` which invokes hotspot method of `JVM_StartThread` (hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp), there is a class `JavaThread` may contain the memory structure for local variables in thread stack.
- if `private static boolean test = true;`; then `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs ==> jvm`, `jvm->jvm_api->AttachCurrentThread ==> env`, `env->env_api->(FindClass, GetStaticFieldID, SetStaticBooleanField) ==> test[true ==> false]`

Comment: Generally this is not possible. `test` variable may not even exist in memory. As soon `main` method is JIT-compiled, there will be unconditional infinite loop, because the compiler realizes that `test` value never changes, and optimizes it out.

Comment: @apangin thx for the comment. how about the updated one? The real purpose is that I would like to patch memory of a local variable of a function call.

Comment: have you considered using the debugger protocol instead?

Comment: @DozParp Even in the updated example `test` variable may not have a location in memory - it may be cached in CPU registers. JVM does not record a mapping between original variables and their actual locations in compiled code unless JVM is started with debug agent.

Comment: Are you sure you can't use the Java debugger or the protocol it uses.  That will be a lot simpler.

Comment: thx all and yes the case is that the java program is started without any debug options.. @apangin the real goal is to exit the program normally. thus we need not get test actually addrees (for gdb, test value should be stored somewhere, so we can patch it in theory as long as we find it, register is also has an address on cpu and function call may push it into stack). alternatively since jvm may have jit to generate a segment of native code for the byte code, is there any way to pause jvm and use jvm low level api to archive the goal?

Comment: @apangin continue from above. use `javap -c Test.class` we can see iload_1 before every compare; jit may compile and optimize to mov eax, 1 and whatever. could you have some guidance on how can i trigger to regenerate native code (or find the native code block for the method, i guess reflect mechanism may record something to link generated native code and method signature?) with making use of low-level function in libjvm.so (jvm.dll)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some cases it is possible to get local variable addresses using HotSpot Serviceability Agent. I've made a sample agent that prints extended stack traces with local variable info:

```
import sun.jvm.hotspot.code.Location;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.code.LocationValue;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.code.NMethod;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.code.ScopeValue;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.code.VMRegImpl;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.Address;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.OopHandle;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.interpreter.OopMapCacheEntry;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.Method;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.Oop;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.CompiledVFrame;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.InterpretedVFrame;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.JavaThread;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.JavaVFrame;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VM;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VMReg;
import sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool;

import java.util.List;

public class Frames extends Tool {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (JavaThread thread = VM.getVM().getThreads().first(); thread != null; thread = thread.next()) {
            System.out.println(thread.getThreadName() + ", id = " + thread.getOSThread().threadId());
            for (JavaVFrame vf = thread.getLastJavaVFrameDbg(); vf != null; vf = vf.javaSender()) {
                dumpFrame(vf);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private void dumpFrame(JavaVFrame vf) {
        Method method = vf.getMethod();
        String className = method.getMethodHolder().getName().asString().replace('/', '.');
        String methodName = method.getName().asString() + method.getSignature().asString();
        System.out.println("  # " + className + '.' + methodName + " @ " + vf.getBCI());

        if (vf.isCompiledFrame()) {
            dumpCompiledFrame(((CompiledVFrame) vf));
        } else {
            dumpInterpretedFrame(((InterpretedVFrame) vf));
        }
    }

    private void dumpCompiledFrame(CompiledVFrame vf) {
        if (vf.getScope() == null) {
            return;
        }

        NMethod nm = vf.getCode();
        System.out.println("    * code=[" + nm.codeBegin() + "-" + nm.codeEnd() + "], pc=" + vf.getFrame().getPC());

        List locals = vf.getScope().getLocals();
        for (int i = 0; i < locals.size(); i++) {
            ScopeValue sv = (ScopeValue) locals.get(i);
            if (!sv.isLocation()) continue;

            Location loc = ((LocationValue) sv).getLocation();
            Address addr = null;
            String regName = "";

            if (loc.isRegister()) {
                int reg = loc.getRegisterNumber();
                addr = vf.getRegisterMap().getLocation(new VMReg(reg));
                regName = ":" + VMRegImpl.getRegisterName(reg);
            } else if (loc.isStack() && !loc.isIllegal()) {
                addr = vf.getFrame().getUnextendedSP().addOffsetTo(loc.getStackOffset());
            }

            String value = getValue(addr, loc.getType());
            System.out.println("    [" + i + "] " + addr + regName + " = " + value);
        }
    }

    private void dumpInterpretedFrame(InterpretedVFrame vf) {
        Method method = vf.getMethod();
        int locals = (int) (method.isNative() ? method.getSizeOfParameters() : method.getMaxLocals());
        OopMapCacheEntry oopMask = method.getMaskFor(vf.getBCI());

        for (int i = 0; i < locals; i++) {
            Address addr = vf.getFrame().addressOfInterpreterFrameLocal(i);
            String value = getValue(addr, oopMask.isOop(i) ? Location.Type.OOP : Location.Type.NORMAL);
            System.out.println("    [" + i + "] " + addr + " = " + value);
        }
    }

    private String getValue(Address addr, Location.Type type) {
        if (type == Location.Type.INVALID || addr == null) {
            return "(invalid)";
        } else if (type == Location.Type.OOP) {
            return "(oop) " + getOopName(addr.getOopHandleAt(0));
        } else if (type == Location.Type.NARROWOOP) {
            return "(narrow_oop) " + getOopName(addr.getCompOopHandleAt(0));
        } else if (type == Location.Type.NORMAL) {
            return "(int) 0x" + Integer.toHexString(addr.getJIntAt(0));
        } else {
            return "(" + type + ") 0x" + Long.toHexString(addr.getJLongAt(0));
        }
    }

    private String getOopName(OopHandle hadle) {
        if (hadle == null) {
            return "null";
        }
        Oop oop = VM.getVM().getObjectHeap().newOop(hadle);
        return oop.getKlass().getName().asString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Frames().execute(args);
    }
}
```

To run it:

```
java -cp $JAVA_HOME/lib/sa-jdi.jar:. Frames PID
```

This will attach to Java process `PID` and print the stacktraces like

```
main, id = 30920
  # java.lang.Thread.sleep(J)V @ 0
  # Test.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V @ 15
    [0] 0x00007f075a857918 = (oop) [Ljava/lang/String;
    [1] 0x00007f075a857910 = (int) 0x1
    [2] 0x00007f075a857908 = (int) 0x0
```

Here `main` is Java thread name; `30920` is native thread ID; `@ 15` is bytecode index.

The line `[1] 0x00007f075a857910 = (int) 0x1` means that the local variable #1 is located at address 0x00007f075a857910 and has the value 1. This is exactly the variable you are interested in.

The local variable information is reliable for interpreted methods, but not always for compiled methods. However, compiled methods will have an extra line with an address of the code, so you can disassemble and inspect it in gdb.

Comment: that's cool, thx so much, very detailed stack trace! :D just wonder how hotspot works there. do you have any book or document page about it?

Comment: @DozParp https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/hotspot_serviceability_agent_api_javadoc

Comment: @apangin , Can you kindly help to give the details for "compiled methods will have an extra line with an address of the code, so you can disassemble and inspect it in gdb." ? As I know compiled Java methods cannot be display from the call stack trace as gdb just display the native methods, so how can it be disassemble and inspect it in gdb? It is better if you can kindly help to give an example for checking the variable value for jitted methods with GDB. Please let me know if I need to create a new question.

Comment: @apangin , BTW, besides the variable value and the address,  is it possible to get the variable name? For example int abcd =123; how to get the name abcd?

Comment: @Jason Yes, if a class file contains debug information. See [`Method.getLocalVariableName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/serviceabilityagent/sun/jvm/hotspot/oops/Method.html#getLocalVariableName-int-int-)

Comment: @apangin, I  found the getLocalVariableName(int bci, int slot) need the bci, and I got it by LocalVariableTable[i].getStartBCI() , however if the LocalVariableTable info is turn off when compiling, this way doesn't work, and especially I found this way doesn't display the variable name for Array.So may I need if there are better way to get the bci or better way to display the variable name?

Comment: @Jacky If Java sources are compiled without debug info, local variable names will not be available.

Comment: @apangin ,BTW , why the local variable information is reliable for interpreted methods, but not always for compiled methods ?It is a bug of SA or there is some technical barrier?

Comment: @Jason Because compiled methods do not preserve local variables. Some variables may be optimized away altogether. SA can do nothing about that.